# Escaping awk parameters inside a Bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to store an awk command in a variable for later using in an automated script.

How do I store a command in a variable?

```
AUTO_SCRIPT="cp a b"
```

How do I run the stored command?

```
$AUTO_SCRIPT
```

Now I want to store an awk command in this script:

```
awk -v par="eth0" '/^iface/ && $2==par {print}' /etc/network/interfaces
```

(This awk normally would print something like **iface eth0 inet dhcp**.

So I want to store it for later execution:

```
AUTO_SCRIPT="awk -v par=\"eth0\" '/^iface/ && $2==par {print}' /etc/network/interfaces"
```

However when trying to execute:

```
$AUTO_SCRIPT
awk: cmd. line:1: '/^iface/
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

What have I tried?
Almost everything. Escaping apostrophes with \ character. Using qoute character instead of apostrophes. Trying with ( and ) characters and so on. Nothing works.

I would need some good idea here.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) As it says, "Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!" Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, there are a number of alternatives that're listed in the FAQ.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES. Too easy to overwrite sensitive variables like PATH.

Comment: See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, establishing all-caps names as used for environment and shell variables meaningful to the shell or POSIX-defined tools, and reserving names with at least one lowercase character for application use: Using lowercase names for your own variables is not just a good idea, it's actually enshrined in POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

Don't save commands in variables, there's no reason to, its cludgy and error-prone. Just create a shell function that calls the awk script instead. For example (the `$` is my prompt):

```
$ auto_script() { echo 'hello world'; }

$ auto_script
hello world
```

Just do the same for your awk script:

```
auto_script() { awk -v par='eth0' '/^iface/ && $2==par' /etc/network/interfaces; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting the command in a function is the cleanest solution. The only other solution is to put the command in an **array**.

```
auto_script=( awk -v par="eth0" '/^iface/ && $2==par {print}' /etc/network/interfaces )
```

and then execute it like this

```
"${auto_script[@]}"
```

Read that BashFAQ #50 link you were given.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you cannot unless you use another mechanism like arrays.

When you call `$AUTO_SCRIPT` the shell splits the content by whitespace resulting in the following arguments: `awk`, `-v`, `par=\"eth0\"`, `'/^iface/`, `&&`, `$2==par` ,`{print}'`, `/etc/network/interfaces`. As a result you awk(1) does not get a proper program to run and you get an error.

Comment: Read the bash FAQ link in the comments for the question.